# Need to dynamically change the simple-page-master's master-name

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an xml document as shown below. Each repeating doc is a page in PDF file

```
<AFPXMLFile>
    <docs>
      <regList>
           <region>1</region>
           <secList>
               <col>1</col>
               <lines></lines>
          </secList>
     </regList>
     <regList>
         <region>2</region>
         <secList>
               <col>2</col>
               <lines>
                  <line>IBM BELGIUM xxx</line>
                  <line>xxxxxx</line>
                  <line>xxxx</line>
              </lines>
         </secList>
     </regList>
     <regList></regList>
     <regList></regList>
  </docs>
  <docs></docs>
 </AFPXMLFile>
```

My XSL is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
exclude-result-prefixes="fo">

<xsl:template match="AFPXMLFile">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:simple-page-master page-width="21cm" page-height="29.7cm"  margin-top="1.27cm" margin-bottom="1.27cm" margin-left="1.75cm" master-name="A4">
  <fo:region-body   margin-top="1mm" margin-bottom="1mm"/>
  <fo:region-before extent="0mm"/>
  <fo:region-after  extent="0mm"/>
  <fo:region-start  writing-mode="tb-rl" precedence="true" extent="10mm" />  
</fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" font-family="sans-serif">
<xsl:for-each select="docs">
    <xsl:for-each select="./regList">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="region = 1">
               <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./secList/lines">
                        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt" color="purple">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                           </fo:block>                                 
                        </xsl:for-each>
                     </xsl:for-each>
                </fo:static-content>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="region = 2">
               <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./secList/lines">
                        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                                <fo:block font-size="4pt" padding-before="4pt" text-align="left" color="green">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </fo:block> 
                        </xsl:for-each>
                     </xsl:for-each>
                 </fo:static-content>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="region = 3">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./secList/lines">
                        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt" color="blue">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </fo:block>
                         </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </fo:static-content>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="region = 4">
               <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./secList">
                        <xsl:for-each select="./lines">
                            <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                                <fo:block font-size="8pt" color="orange">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                               </fo:block>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                     </xsl:for-each>
               </fo:flow>      
            </xsl:when>  
        </xsl:choose>                        
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run the transformation I get the following error:

> org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: For "fo:page-sequence", "fo:static-content" must be declared before "fo:flow"! (No context info available)

This I suspect because it is repeating the static content region for each page. So I believe I need to change the simple-page-master:master-name for every page
I need help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [XSL-FO recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_page-sequence), the contents of 'fo:page-sequence' is:

> (title?,folio-prefix?,folio-suffix?,**static-content***,**flow+**)

which means that all the `fo:static-content` elements must be **before** the `fo:flow` elements.

Your stylesheet dynamically creates either `fo:static-content` (if `region` is 1, 2 or 3) or `fo:flow` (if `region` is 4). From the reduced input file in your question it is not possible to see whether the `regList` elements are alway correctly sorted, so that they produce a valid output when sequentially processed.

Moreover, as each `docs` element represents a different document with different headers/footers, you have to create distinct `fo:page-sequence`s instead of a single one (otherwise you get too many static contents and flows for a single page sequence):

```
<xsl:for-each select="docs">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" font-family="sans-serif">
        <xsl:for-each select="./regList">
            ....
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Moreover, there is a *strange* thing in the stylesheet: you map an `fo:static-content` to the `xsl-region-body` region, and the `fo:flow` to the `xsl-region-after` region, which is quite unusual. If the "real" content for the body region is the one with `region` = 3, you must process `region` 1, 2 and 4 *first*, and *then* region 3:

```
<xsl:for-each select="docs">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" font-family="sans-serif">
        <!-- create static contents -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./regList[region != '3']"/>
        <!-- create flow -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./regList[region = '3']"/>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:for-each>
```

with an additional template to match `reglist`:

```
<xsl:template match="regList">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="region = '1'">
           <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <xsl:for-each select="./secList/lines">
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                        <fo:block font-size="8pt" color="purple">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                       </fo:block>                                 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:static-content>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="region = '2'">
           <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
                <xsl:for-each select="./secList/lines">
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                            <fo:block font-size="4pt" padding-before="4pt" text-align="left" color="green">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </fo:block> 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </xsl:for-each>
             </fo:static-content>    
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="region = '3'">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:for-each select="./secList/lines">
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                        <fo:block font-size="8pt" color="blue">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </fo:block>
                     </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:flow>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="region = '4'">
           <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <xsl:for-each select="./secList">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./lines">
                        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt" color="orange">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                           </fo:block>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </xsl:for-each>
           </fo:static-content>      
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

or several, smaller templates:

```
<xsl:template match="reglist[region = '1']">
   <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <xsl:for-each select="./secList/lines">
            <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                <fo:block font-size="8pt" color="purple">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </fo:block>                                 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:static-content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reglist[region = '2']">
    ...
</xsl:template>

...
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I am new to the FOP. Yes, regList is always sorted as 1,2,3 and 4 in a docs element. The XSL works for the first page of the PDF and fails when it encounters region 1 again for the next page.  The reason I have fo:flow for the region-after is when I added is before any other region it was giving me error saying all static content should come before flow. I have no idea how I can modify the loop so that they wont repeat. Could you please provide me pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I used your first solution and it is working.