# XSL-FO: How can I control which simple-page-master is used for each element via attributes?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I would like to add the simple-page-master name to each element in xml that should be used for that element.
Consecutive elements with the same simple page master should be rendered consecutively.
An element that has a different simple page master as attribute should start on a new page.

Each element should be responsible for its simple page master.

According to [Need to dynamically change the simple-page-master's master-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641048/need-to-dynamically-change-the-simple-page-masters-master-name) 
I've already tried

```html
...
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="pagemasterTemplate"/>

</fo:root>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="element" mode="pagemasterTemplate">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="pagemaster">
            <fo:page-sequence>
                <xsl:attribute name="master-reference"><xsl:value-of select ="pagemaster"/></xsl:attribute>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                       <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

but my XML elements nest across multiple hierarchy levels and I don't get the depth I need.

These are my examples simple-page master

```xml
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="RED-PAGE">
    <fo:region-body backgound-color="red"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>

<fo:simple-page-master master-name="BLUE-PAGE">
    <fo:region-body backgound-color="blue"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>

<fo:simple-page-master master-name="YELLOW-PAGE">
    <fo:region-body backgound-color="yellow"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

Example XML

```xml
<root>
  <report>
    <reportelements>
        <section name="sec 1">
            <pagemaster>RED-PAGE</pagemaster>
            <reportelements>
                <chapter name="cha 1.1">
                    <pagemaster>RED-PAGE</pagemaster>
                    <reportelements>
                        <paragraph name="par 1.1.1">
                            <reportelements/>
                            <pagemaster>RED-PAGE</pagemaster>
                        </paragraph>
                    </reportelements>
                </chapter>
            </reportelements>
        </section>
        <section name="sec 2">
            <pagemaster>BLUE-PAGE</pagemaster>
            <reportelements>
                <chapter name="cha 2.1">
                    <pagemaster>YELLOW-PAGE</pagemaster>
                    <reportelements>
                        <picture name="pic 2.1.1">
                            <reportelements/>
                            <pagemaster>YELLOW-PAGE</pagemaster>
                        </picture>
                    </reportelements>
                </chapter>
            </reportelements>
        </section>
    </reportelements>
  </report>
</root>
```

What i want is an Output that looks like this:

```
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|   RED-PAGE   | 
|   sec 1      |
|   cha 1.1    |
|   par 1.1.1  |
|              |
|              |
|              |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|   BLUE-PAGE  | 
|   sec 2      |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|  YELLOW-PAGE | 
|   cha 2.1    |
|   pic 2.1.1  |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT (not XSL-FO) are you using?

Comment: @TonyGraham, the XSLT has `xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="pagemaster"` so it seems to be XSLT 2/3.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply change `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="pagemasterTemplate"/>` to

```
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//element" group-adjacent="pagemaster">
           <fo:page-sequence master-reference="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

and then set up an

```
<xsl:template match="element">
  <fo:block>
    <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></fo:block>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

then I think you should get the "page" structure you want, I am not sure which content needs to be output and whether it needs to preserve some nesting, the above would somehow flatten the nested input to some flat output

Comment: What can i do to add some Static content according to what kind of element i have? I dont only have "element" but also "section", "chapter", "paragraph" etc...

Comment: @CrazyEight, can you edit the input sample so that I can see the structure? You can of course process child elements or child nodes with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` or `<xsl:template apply-templates select="section"/>` and then write templates producing the wanted output e.g. `<xsl:template match="section"><fo:block>... <xsl:apply-templates/> ...</fo:block></xsl:template>`, the only issue you need to be aware of and need to take care of is that you don't recurse endlessly on the nested `subElements/element`.

Comment: i put my actual xml structure under the example xml :)

Comment: instead of `<xsl:for-each-group select=".//element" group-adjacent="pagemaster">` i select `<xsl:for-each-group select=".//reportelements/*" group-adjacent="pagemaster">`

Comment: If you continue to use the `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>` then of course you just need to set up different templates e.g. `<xsl:template match="section"><fo:block><fo:block>Section <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></fo:block></fo:block></xsl:template>` as one template for the `section` elements, then further customized templates for the other elements you want to have a different output for. It might be better to ask a new, separate question on this, as it seems the `name` attribute is gone and the FO result you want for the different elements is not clear.

Comment: I just edit the xml again... 
If i set up templates like u said e.g `<xsl:template match="section">` i cant handle static content inside of this template because i am already in my page sequence...

Comment: Ok i have changed the example xml

Comment: @CrazyEight, I can't understand with all those edits what you really want to achieve or what kind of FO content you want to generate for the input, perhaps ask a new question or wait until someone else perhaps grasps from your ASCII layout which FO you want.

Comment: I dont understand? You already answered my main question... 
```xml
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//reportelements/*" group-adjacent="pagemaster">
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
             </fo:flow>
       </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

That fixed it!
I'm just wondering how to get static content in there according to the different elements (section, chapter, paragraph) that i have

Comment: @CrazyEight, if the original question is answered then I think it is better to ask the other question separately, given all the necessary details of the XML you have, the FO you want, the XSLT you now have and showing which part is still missing, it is not clear to me what you consider static content, neither in the input or in any FO you want.